# Recurring Payment Paypal Express Checkout .....

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

When i was following paypal Existing Example i can not get the order information in paypal express checkout how could i do that i am giving my where i am not getting oder information as follows -

```
/** SetExpressCheckout NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Initiate an Express Checkout transaction. 
*/

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('super_secret_username');
    $API_Password = urlencode('super_secret_password');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('super_secret_signature');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentAmount = urlencode('105.87');
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
$paymentType = urlencode('Authorization');              // or 'Sale' or 'Order'

$returnURL = urlencode("http://localhost/paypal/new/success.php");
$cancelURL = urlencode('http://localhost/paypal/new/cencel.php');

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&Amt=$paymentAmount&ReturnUrl=$returnURL&CANCELURL=$cancelURL&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";


// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    // Redirect to paypal.com.
    $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);
    $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    }
    header("Location: $payPalURL");
    exit;
} else  {
    exit('SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
```

using this script how do i get the order total .

I need script for Paypal Recurring Payment using Payal Express Checkout. I also need to Update and cancel the recurring payment.

Comment: Ruzdi Islam, the code you have provided is completely dependant upon the data supplied. Basically, you have not provided enough information. function func(that) {do this[that];}. Is basically what you have provided. Provide the list of variables you are sending to PayPal so your method can be investigated. Look at the L_PAYMENTREQUEST variables for express checkout, as you have to submit line items to see them.

Answer (score 0):

To post succsessifuly your code, must set some additional parameters. Also I clean some additional errors that you will find if compare two examples. The main things are:

1. `$returnURL` and `$cancelURL` must be a real URL and without method `urlencode()`
2. `$version` must be set to `urlencode('124.0')`;
3. Parameters for `SetExpressCheckout` must be set as in the example.
4. I recommend to test on live just set the price in `$0.01`

   Follow the example below:

```
 


/** SetExpressCheckout NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Initiate an Express Checkout transaction. 
*/

$environment = 'live';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'


/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */


function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {

    global $environment;



    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.

    $API_UserName = urlencode('super_secret_username');

    $API_Password = urlencode('super_secret_password');

    $API_Signature = urlencode('super_secret_signature');

    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";

    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {

        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";

    }

    $version = urlencode('124.0');



    // Set the curl parameters.

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);



    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);



    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.

    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature&$nvpStr_";



    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);



    // Get response from the server.

    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);


    if(!$httpResponse) {

        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');

    }



    // Extract the response details.

    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);



    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();

    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {

        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);

        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {

            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];

        }

    }



    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {

        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");

    }



    return $httpParsedResponseAr;

}


// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentAmount = urlencode('105.87');
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');                         // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
$paymentType = urlencode('Authorization');              // or 'Sale' or 'Order'


$returnURL = "http://localhost/paypal/new/success.php"; // Please provide a real URL !!!!!

$cancelURL = 'http://localhost/paypal/new/cencel.php'; // Please provide a real URL !!!!!


//Parameters for SetExpressCheckout, which will be sent to PayPal   

$paypal_data =  array(
    'RETURNURL'                     => $returnURL,

    'CANCELURL'                     => $cancelURL,

    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => $$currencyID,

    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'=> 'SALE',

    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'         => 'Hosted Saas Tier 1 and Community Management Services',

    'PAYMENTACTION'                 => $paymentType,

    'L_BILLINGTYPE0'                => 'RecurringPayments',

    'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'=> 'Description of Community Management Services',

    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'      => 'Community Management Services 8 hours for $0.01',

    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0'    => '010101',

    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'       => '1',

    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'       => $paymentAmount,



    /**
     * If you want second recurring payment in the same session
     * 'L_BILLINGTYPE1'             => 'RecurringPayments',
     * 'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION1'=> 'Description of Hosted Saas Tier 1',
     * 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1'       => 'Hosted Saas Tier 1',
     * 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1' => '212121',
     * 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1'        => '1',
     * 'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1'        => '0.02',
     */

    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'      => $paymentAmount,
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'          => $paymentAmount

);

$nvpStr = http_build_query($paypal_data);

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.

$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);


if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {

    // Redirect to paypal.com.

    $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);

    $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";

    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {

        $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";

    }

    header("Location: $payPalURL");

    exit;

} else  {

    exit('SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));

}
```